# JUnit Version in Netbeans 7.3, 7.4

Tags: netbeans-7

Why latest versions of NetBeans (7.3, 7.4) do not have JUnit 4.11 ?
Rather they come with JUnit 3.8.2 and 4.10

In fact as seen in Maven Repository page of JUnit, 4.11 was last updated in Nov 2012, which is almost a year old !

Answer (score 2):

My guess is, as NetBeans has very good support for Maven, most developers are including JUnit explicitly as a dependency within their POM files. I don't think I've used the copy of JUnit in NetBeans for several years.

As for the age of JUnit 4.11, the JUnit API and implementation are pretty stable and, as time goes on, I use Hamcrest and Mockito to augment what JUnit provides.